# SQL Server Stored Procedure select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I can't figure out how to set the values if `Power`, `ChangeRate`, and `Type` are null. I still want it to return rest of the values even if those are not in the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.up_getTestData
(@Chip int)
AS
   DECLARE @Type char(2), @ChangeRate real, @Power bit

   SELECT @Type = Type  
   FROM Spectrum 
   WHERE ChipID = @Chip

   IF(@Type is null)
      //SET @Type = 'NA'
      //or Go to the bottom statement ??
      SELECT @ChangeRate = ChangeRate 
      FROM TempCycle 
      WHERE ChipID = @Chip

   IF(@ChangeRate is null)
      //Go to the bottom statement ??
      //SET  @ChangeRate = '0.0'
      SELECT @Power = Power 
      FROM TempCycle 
      WHERE ChipID = @Chip

   IF(@Power is null)
        // I want it to still go the bottom statement. I put just return 
        // but that's not right since it wouldn't return anything than??
        // or I did SET @Power = 'false'
   ELSE
      SELECT 
          Chips.Chip_ID AS ChipID, 
          Chip_Number, Test_Module.ModuleTypeID, 
          Test_Module.PID, Test_Module.Component1, Test_Module.Component2, 
          Test_Module.Parameter1, Test_Module.Parameter2, Test_Module.Parameter3, 
          Test_Module.Parameter4, Test_Module.Parameter5, 
          Test_Module.Parameter6, Spectrum.Type, TempCycle.Power, TempCycle.ChangeRate 
      FROM 
          Chips 
      INNER JOIN 
          Test_Module ON Chips.Chip_Number = Test_Module.Module_Name 
      INNER JOIN 
          Spectrum ON Test_Module.ModuleSpec_TestID =  Spectrum.TestID 
      INNER JOIN 
          TempCycle ON Test_Module.ModuleTemp_TestID = TempCycle.TestID 
      WHERE 
          Chip_ID = @Chip
RETURN
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What kind of output are you trying to get? What do you want to do with the `@Type`, `@ChangeRate`, and `@Power` variables?

Comment: Could you post the expected out ? what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: @RobertHarris I'm displaying the data on aspx page so if the value is null, I just want to display it as being empty otherwise display the values from database.

Comment: @user2994144, my answer below assumes you want to show 'NA', 'false' and '0.0' instead of NULL for Type, Power and ChangeRate respectively. If you'd rather they simply be empty, replace those in my script with empty strings (or double single-quotes).

Comment: @Zec I tried both coalesce and ISNULL but it's still not returning the data I want. I was hoping it would :)

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. I believe it's not showing you what you want because there are no Spectrum or TempCycle records for some Test_Modules. As such, the INNER JOIN will filter those Test_Modules out (must exist on both sides).

Comment: @Zec Yes, it works if there are values for both Spectrum and TempCycle. I did if else where it would not INNER JOIN with Spectrum and TempCycle but than the program complains it doesn't know what ChangeRate, Power, and Type are.

Comment: OK, I suppose that means there is still a problem. The Left Outer Joins below should resolve your program's complaint. Could you provide more detail on the remaining issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is coalesce (or ISNULL):

```
SELECT 
  Chips.Chip_ID AS ChipID, 
  Chip_Number, 
  Test_Module.ModuleTypeID, 
  Test_Module.PID,     
  Test_Module.Component1, 
  Test_Module.Component2, 
  Test_Module.Parameter1, 
  Test_Module.Parameter2, 
  Test_Module.Parameter3, 
  Test_Module.Parameter4, 
  Test_Module.Parameter5, 
  Test_Module.Parameter6, 
  coalesce(Spectrum.Type, 'NA') as Type, 
  coalesce(TempCycle.Power, 'false') as Power, 
  coalesce(TempCycle.ChangeRate, '0.0') as ChangeRate 
FROM 
  Chips INNER JOIN Test_Module 
    ON Chips.Chip_Number = Test_Module.Module_Name 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Spectrum 
    ON Test_Module.ModuleSpec_TestID =  Spectrum.TestID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TempCycle 
    ON Test_Module.ModuleTemp_TestID = TempCycle.TestID 
WHERE 
  Chip_ID = @Chip
```